# Web's demo of jQuery tablesorter plugin does not work in my Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to use jQuery to sort tables, but I open the [tablesorter site](http://tablesorter.com/), It's demo doesn't work in my Firefox3.6.18 and IE7.0, However it work well in Chrome and Safari.

tablesorter says:
tablesorter has been tested successfully in the following browsers with Javascript enabled:
* Firefox 2+
* Internet Explorer 6+

Why I can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a lot of problems with table sorter.  My solution, [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html).  Using datatables is extremely easy.  You design your table as you normally would.  In the $() ready function add
    $('#tableId').dataTable()

That is it.  You can now sort each column.  You can also download and add column filter to search each column.

add 
    .columnFilter()

Column filter setup is explained [here](http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-column-filters/).

Hope this helps!